# How do I create a non-spatial web map

Tags: web-mapping

This question pertains to mapping arbitrary data using web map tile technology.

Most of the time the data source for a web map is spatial in nature (OSM).

I'd like to create a site map using the cartographic sense of the word.  Rather than a boring list of links I'd like to model a site map after cartography from the [Metro](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Wash-dc-metro-map.png) in Washington DC.  This could be used as a sort of alternative to a standard navigation bar.

Is it possible to churn any old image/vector into a set of tiles at different zoom levels, if I were to say, draw vectors manually with inkscape?

Comment: Like this? https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/maptype-image-overlay

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be tied to any projected coordinate system.

Comment: You will need some sort of coordinate system in you want too zoom in an out of any custom map. tile size 256px by 256 is mathematically correct for maps tiles in Mercator.

Comment: So I could make a map of an image on Mercator without an underlying basemap.  How would I get a custom image into Mercator?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code with Leaflet, you can set the image to embed in the mapcontrol,with or without a basemap :

```
function init(){
    var map = L.map('map', {
        maxZoom: 24,
        minZoom: 1,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0, 0], 1);

    map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds([0,500], [500,0]));

    var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg'
    var imageBounds = [[250,0], [0,250]];

    L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: Cutting image into tiles: http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html

Comment: i think it is simpler to serve the whole image by geoserver or mapserver , so you won't need to make tiles